# Is there only one base with the trivial topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set with the trivial topology. Is $B=\{X\}$ the only possible base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost. There's another one: $\{\emptyset,X\}$.

Comment: So easy I didn't realise. Thanks